# Instead of update trigger on view is not fired automatically unless manually updated on View

Tags: oracle

I have a view to fetch list of my project specific packages from all_objects in Oracle DB, which will fetch the name, status, created and last DDL for all objects with wildcard operator specific to my project requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW ALL_XYZ_PACKAGES_VW
AS
   SELECT object_name,status, object_type,created,last_ddl_time
     FROM all_objects
    WHERE object_name LIKE 'XYZ_%'
     AND object_type IN ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY');
```

And my requirement is to fire a trigger which sends an email notification when any of my package gets Invalid due to some DB Link missing or dependent object is missing or any wrong code deployed with logical errors.
    So following is the trigger i have created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER notify_invalidobjects_trigger 
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON ALL_XYZ_PACKAGES_VW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.STATUS = 'INVALID') THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Following mentioned Package is in INVALID state: '|| :OLD.OBJECT_NAME); -- Email notification part will e written here
  ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('In Else Block');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Issue:
1) When i am manually updating the package status as INVALID in my view with an update statement, trigger is getting fired.

BUT when the package is automatically getting Invalid, when i am making some dependent object as `Invalid or by wrong code deployment`,

```
TRIGGER IS NOT GETTING FIRED EVEN THE STATUS IS 
GETTING INAVLID AUTOMATICALLY IN MY VIEW AND ALL_OBJECTS.
```

Could any one suggest me what i need to check or update in code.

Note: I thought of using After Update trigger, but its not allowing me to use the same on views.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger on the view will not fire because the view is not updated. Your view is no more and no less then a stored select statement. If you don't need "live response" I'd suggest to just change to a procedure for query all_objects and send the mail and run it via job.

Comment: Thanks for the information but by using the job, it will be dependent on timestamp. I would like to send a mail as the package gets Invalid due to any reason. Also please suggest any way to filter my project specific packages from all_objects (bcz of which i used the view). Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Are you aware that `all_objects` shows invalid objects that not really are invalid? Objects can get automatically invalid if you change a depending object even if no object is realy invalid at all. I.e. a package if a used table is altered. They are recompiled in background as the package is executed or can be recompiled by `alter [OBJECT_NAME] recompile;`. But until than they appear as invalid in the objects view.

Comment: Yes right. So whenever that package is Invalid due to some dependency (as u mentioned) or by some wrong code deployment, i need to send out an email. So how shall i trigger an event, if any object gets Invalid in all_objects and how shall i filter my project specific objects (as we cant use View here) Please suggest

Comment: Sorry the only solution following your idea so far I can think of quick is a "no-go" ;) I don't understand the use of raising so many false alarms anyway. In my opinon the concept doesn't make sense without at least recompiling before querying. Mayby you should give DDL-Triggers a closer look: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ddl_triggers.htm to find another solution?

Comment: @user4422741 - dependencies shouldn't be lost and 'wrong code deployment' shouldn't happen in a way you need to monitor - if you think you need to check for this constantly then that suggests you're allowing uncontrolled changes, or at best that your code is dependent on other code you have no control over and which might be updated without your knowledge. This seems to be a deployment/management issue that you're trying to put a sticking plaster over, so maybe you need to rethink your procedures instead?

Comment: Yes correct Alex, But it happens that we r  not aware that some dependent object from cross team is Invalid bcz of which our object got Invalid, and later on when we get a defect of order failure because of few inavlids, we need to search and identify why it failed. So instead of waiting for any defect to come and then analyse that the package got invalid, i am planning to get it done automatically, which means if any pckg get INVALID, we shud be intimated with an Email.

Comment: @user4422741 - you and the other team should both be checking if anything in invalidated as part of your deployments, and resolving it immediately; but you should catch this sort of thing before you get to production anyway. If you really think you need it then a regular job - daily, hourly, or whatever you think necessary - is the way to go. That would allow some time for temporary invalidation to be sorted out to reduce false-positives, too.

Comment: Its only for the code in test environment, where in different cross track teams deploy their code regularly. 
I was planning to do the said task by Triggers , but as discussed above all_objects is a view and we cant fire a trigger over that which should send mail, if any package get invalid.

I was thinking not to use the Scheduler or Jobs, but now think thats the only solution left.

Please suggest, if any other solution for this requirement.

And thanks much for your time and suggestions